# glob is unable to extract all the fies from the command line variable

Tags: python, glob

I am using glob.glob command in my python program and it works fine when i give the whole path in the python script. If i give the path as a command line argument, glob doesnt work.

```
 path=r'/home/*/sale'
 all = glob.glob(path + "/x.txt")
 print all

 Output:

 ['/home/x1/sale/x.txt', '/home/x2/sale/x.txt']
```

but when I do path from argument as below it does not work.

```
 path = sys.argv[1]
 all = glob.glob(path + "/x.txt")
 print all
 Output:

 ['/home/x1/sale/x.txt']
```

It picks up only the first file.

Could someone please help me understand what I am missing here. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the commandline arguments you use while calling your code

Comment: when you use `*` in command line then system may replace it with value. You may have to put text in single quotas marks `''` in command line. Check what you have in `sys.arg[1]` - you may have `/home/x1/sale`. Check also if you don't have `sys.arg[2]` with `'/home/x2/sale'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `*` in command line then system (`Linux` or rather `bash`) replaces it with value.

So you run

```
script.py /home/*/sale
```

but `bash` replace it with

```
script.py /home/x1/sale /home/x2/sale
```

and you have `/home/x1/sale` in `sys.argv[1]` and `/home/x2/sale` in sys.argv[2]

You have to put text in single quotas marks `' '` in command line.

```
script.py '/home/*/sale'
```

and it will not replace `*` and system's variables (like `$HOME`)

Or double quotas marks `" "` and it will not replace `*` but it will replace variables.

```
script.py "/home/*/sale"
```

Comment: ... But of course the correct  way to do that is to  loop over `sys.argv[1:]` and pick up all the command-line arguments, and let the user use globbing on the command line if they want to.

Comment: Thank you adding quotes fixed the issue